# overlay in react setting overflow failed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Why this code won't work in react??

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        if (this.props.show !== nextProps.show) {
            document.body.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
            document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        }

        if(nextProps.show === false){
            document.body.style.overflowX = 'auto';
            document.body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to hide scroll bar on an overlay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. But following code will change overflow styles based on `nextProps.show` value correctly.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.show !== nextProps.show) {
      document.body.style.overflowX = nextProps.show ? 'hidden' : 'auto';
      document.body.style.overflowY = nextProps.show ? 'hidden' : 'auto';
  }
}
```

Comment: somehow componentWillReceiveProps doesn't trigger

Comment: Then the given code is not enough to give you an answer. We need to check how you change your `show` prop when there is an overlay.